# Regarding compatibility of Intel Pentium D 805 CPU with new motherboard

Tags: motherboard, processor-socket

I currently have an old  configuration with Intel Pentium D 805 CPU and Intel D101GGC chipset. Now I am planning to upgrade my system except CPU and hard disk since it doesn't fit in the budget.

**QUESTION:**
I am planning to get Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3H Motherboard which has LGA1155 socket. But my processor has PLGA775 socket type. Will my CPU fit in thee new motherboard's socket?

**LINKS:**
CPU specs (Intel site):
http://ark.intel.com/products/27511/Intel-Pentium-D-Processor-805-2M-Cache-2_66-GHz-533-MHz-FSB

New Motherboard specs (Vendor site):
http://www.flipkart.com/gigabyte-ga-b75m-d3h-motherboard/p/itmdacp36gegyeqt?pid=MBDDACP2GUBGFPFM

Comment: Here is link to New Motherboard specs (Manufacturer site):

[LINK](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4150#sp)

Comment: Clearly a PLGA775 CPU can't fit into an LGA1155 socket.

Comment: Well, that sucks.. Then how about this 1st generation Core-i3 CPU? It has FCLGA1156 Socket type. Will it fit on the Gigabyte mobo mentioned above?? [LINK](http://ark.intel.com/products/46473/Intel-Core-i3-540-Processor-4M-Cache-3_06-GHz)

Comment: nope. It will not. The mobo and cpu need to have the exact same socket type. 1156 !=1155.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't fit. Look at http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4150 , it will explain and show the chipset which fits - it even [lists tested models](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/cpu-support-popup.aspx?pid=4150)

Answer (score 1):

Something to consider:

When purchasing a motherboard for upgrade, you should really consider its future potential for upgrades, as well as satisfying the current hardware you own.

If you purchase a motherboard to satisfy your old processor, you are limiting your ability to get a better processor in the future, as there are no current generation processors that use the same socket as your current one.

I always recommend that people who want to upgrade their motherboards update the CPU at the same time and avoid this dilemma entirely.

If you have your heart set on this motherboard, the 1155 socket has many budget options for processors such as the Pentium G620, currently list at $63.99 on Newegg.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819116399

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work. You have to use a CPU with the same socket as your motherboard.